# Clearing selected table in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, xlwings

I use excel as a front end and use python to pick up data from it and insert into sqlite db. once entered, i wish to clear selected fields from MS excel.
Here is the code i have been trying to use via xlwings:
**xw.Range('A6:R50').table.clear_contents()**. This is not working.

It is showing the following error:
NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear_contents'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you would like others to look at your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clear_contents()` on a [range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.clear_contents) or a [worksheet](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/sheet.html#xlwings.Sheet.clear_contents). Examples:

**Clear contents on a range**

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.range("A6:R50").clear_contents()
```

**Clear contents on a worksheet**

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.clear_contents()  # Clears the whole worksheet.
```